# phpredis set() not storing the key, what am I missing?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

This is basic code that I pulled off the internet to test Redis. When setting or getting, I get nothing. I'm suspecting that there is something wrong with my php config, but not sure how to figure out what is going wrong. I've also tried using predis as a client and it too reacts the same way.

```
$connected= $redis->connect('localhost', 6379); //works

if(!$connected) {
    // some other code to handle connection problem
    die( "Cannot connect to redis server.\n" );
}

$redis->set('somekey', 'some value');  // fails

echo $redis->get('somekey'); //fails
```

Comment: FYI...I tested redis using the redis-cli and redis appears to be working properly. The failure is between php client and redis.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having the same issue. I can connect but I can't set.

Answer (score 0):

Check if phpinfo() function displays redis client in the listing.

Also check in redis.conf if requirepass is set to some value, if yes you have to connect with redis using those credentials.